# mongodb database list is empty but i can see the content

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I install the `mongodb` and the `Robomongo` to control it. but when I use the shell to create table and insert something into it,I can see it in the shell but in the `Robomongo` I cannt see it,and the database list show the used space is 0.000GB,here is the picture[image]

I have checked the permission of it own files include the config file and the storage file, it's all 777, the version of the `mongodb` is 3.2.6.

Comment: How many documents have you inserted ?

Comment: maybe 20 ~ 30 documents

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect to your database server using roboMongo?

If yes, then in the roboMongo explorer window,

1. Expand the database you wish to see.
2. expand collections folder. You must be able to see your collection.
3. Right click on the collection and choose "View Documents"

[image]

And if you are not able to connect to the database server, check the connection Address, portNumber, Authentication details etc.

Comment: in the shell i can see 3 tables and some test data in it .The Robomongo is connect to database server, i can see the databases but i cannt see the tables or the test data.

Comment: @unknowerror  1. What do you see when you expand the collections folder? 2. Are you sure you are comparing the same databases in shell and roboMongo. May be your shell is picking up the previously used database. Can you switch to the _database in question_ on you mongo shell and then run the find command. use `use database_name` to switch database

Comment: 1.there is nothing show in the folder. 2 . i only have two databases,on is local,another is my test database named node. I can switch to the test database. here is my another test: i create a collection in the Robomongo,it remind me i have create it successfully, but when i refresh it, the new collection is not exist,and i find it in my mongo shell.

Comment: I see only one database in Robomongo. However, I have 3 databases and I can see their content through mongo shell and nodejs-mongoose connector. Am I missing anything?